# Why is, in SQLite, `SELECT (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) INTERSECT SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4` equal 4 and not 3?

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, union, intersect

In SQLite, if I type:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) INTERSECT SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
```

I get the result `4`. How is that possible?

`SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 SELECT 3` is `(1, 2, 3)`, right? And `SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4` is `(3, 4)`. So, the intersect should be `3`, right? What am I getting wrong?

EDIT: Saying that `INTERSECT` is evaluated first does not answer my question, as `((1,2,3) INTERSECT (3)) UNION (4)` is `(3,4)`, rather than `4`.

Comment: @MitchWheat Err... That does not answer my question. I'd still expect 3 as a result, rather than 4.

Comment: @MitchWheat INTERSECT does **not** have higher precedence: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound_select_statements

Comment: @MitchWheat: "When three or more simple SELECTs are connected into a compound SELECT, they group from left to right"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your statement like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) 
INTERSECT 
SELECT 3 
UNION 
SELECT 4
```

you can see that you are combining 3 `SELECT` statements with the operators `UNION` and `INTERSECT`.
All 3 statements should return the same number of columns.
Your 1st statement:

```
SELECT (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3)
```

actually [returns only 1 row with 1 column](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subquery_expressions), [try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=39c3c6a2608c15d2b07938283d2344af), which is the 1st row and the result is `1`.

So your code is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 1 
INTERSECT 
SELECT 3 
UNION 
SELECT 4
```

which returns nothing for `INTERSECT` and finally `UNION` returns `4`.

If you meant to write:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) 
INTERSECT 
SELECT 3 
UNION 
SELECT 4
```

then the result would be `(3, 4)`.